# Parse an array of json object using jq

Tags: jq

I am trying to parse the below json file and store the result into another json file. How do I achieve this ?

```
{
  "Objects": [
    {
      "ElementName": "Test1",
      "ElementArray": ["abc","bcd"],
      "ElementUnit": "4"
    },
    {
      "ElementName": "Test2",
      "ElementArray": ["abc","bcde"],
      "ElementUnit": "8"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result :

```
{
"Test1" :[
"abc","bcd"
],
"Test2" :[
"abc","bcde"
]
}
```

I've tried something on the lines of the below but I seem to be off -

```
jq '[.Objects[].ElementName ,(.Objects[]. ElementArray[])]' user1.json

jq ".Objects[].ElementName .Objects[].ElementArray" ruser1.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output needs to be wrapped in curly braces in order to be a valid JSON object. That said, use `from_entries` to create an object from an array of key-value pairs, which can be produced by accordingly `map`ping the input object's `Objects` array.

```
.Objects | map({key: .ElementName, value: .ElementArray}) | from_entries
```

```json
{
  "Test1": [
    "abc",
    "bcd"
  ],
  "Test2": [
    "abc",
    "bcde"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BKtNFKWEJs)

Answer (score 0):

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/YbjICOd8EJ

You can also use `reduce`

```
reduce .Objects[] as $o ({}; .[$o.ElementName]=$o.ElementArray)
```